# Same style for all tabularx elements

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am pretty new to Latex and I want to ask how do I get the same style for all tabularx elements. 
The heading should be a grey background with white letters and the lines of the table should be in dark blue.

Thanks!

Comment: See the xcolor package, section 2.12 of the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a solution. You can change the background color of the cells.

**Addendum: Excuse me, but I have forgotten the white characters. I have added someone.**

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\definecolor{um}{RGB}{0,33,96}
\begin{document}
\taburulecolor{um}
  \begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|}
   \hline
    \rowcolor{gray}
    \textcolor{white}{1} & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
    1 & 1 & \textcolor{white}{2} \\ \hline
    \rowcolor{darkgray}
    \textcolor{white}{5} & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
  \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I hope I have helped you. If so, could you vote and check the V to accept my answer?